# Dataframe headers get modified on saving as parquet file using glue

Tags: pyspark, parquet, aws-glue

I'm writing a dataframe with headers by partitions to s3 using the below code:

```
df_dynamic = DynamicFrame.fromDF(
    df_columned,
    glue_context,
    "temp_ctx"
)

print("\nUploading parquet to " + destination_path)

glue_context.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    frame=df_dynamic,
    connection_type="s3",
    connection_options={
        "path": destination_path,
        "partitionKeys" : ["partition_id"]
    },
    format_options={
        "header":"true"
    },
    format="glueparquet"
)
```

Once my files are created I see I have #1, #2 added after my column headers.
Example: if my column name is "Doc Data", it gets converted to Doc_Date#1

I thought its a parquet way of saving data.
Then when I try to read from the same files using the below code, my headers are no more the same. Now they come as Doc_Date#1. How do I fix this?

```
str_folder_path = str.format(
    _S3_PATH_FORMAT,
    args['BUCKET_NAME'],
    str_relative_path
)

df_grouped = glue_context.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    "s3", 
    {
        'paths': [str_folder_path], 
        'recurse':True, 
        'groupFiles': 'inPartition', 
        'groupSize': '1048576'
    },
    format_options={
        "header":"true"
    }, 
    format="parquet"
)

return df_grouped.toDF()
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue Resolved!!

Issue was that I had spaces in my column names. Once I replaced them with underscores(_), the issue resolved.